# HTML5 Canvas Move TiledMap Background

Tags: html, canvas, path-finding

At first, sorry for my English :(

I'm having fun with canvas element and i'm trying to make a gamebrowser but i can't solve this problem.

1. I get the map tiles in two dimension array.
2. I get the position player, i translate the context (to draw it in center of the canvas) and then i redraw the map considering the absolute position in the map. But when i move the player, the map dissappear about 1 second (clearRect canvas i think) and after the map appears.

So, my problem is this annoying second with the canvas in black.

The code.

```
function pinta(){
    var mirror = renderToCanvas(canvas.width, canvas.height, function (ctx) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    //antes de pintar debemos calcular la traslacion
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var moverX=canvas.width/2-players[yo].x;
        var moverY=canvas.height/2-players[yo].y;
        ctx.translate(moverX,moverY);
        pinta_terreno();
        pinta_players();

    function pinta_players()
    {
        for( var player in players ) {
            var i=player,
            x=players[i].x;
            y=players[i].y;
            var img=new Image(25,25);
            if(i==2)img.src="/img/player2.png";
            else img.src="/img/player1.png";
            ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
        }
    }   

    function pinta_terreno()
    {
        // donde estoy en tiles
        var min_x=(-canvas.width+players[yo].x)/TAM_TILE;
        var max_x=(canvas.width+players[yo].x)/TAM_TILE;
        var min_y=(-canvas.width+players[yo].y)/TAM_TILE;
        var max_y=(canvas.width+players[yo].y)/TAM_TILE;
        ///////////////////////
            for(var i=min_x;i<=max_x;i++)
                    for(var j=min_y;j<=max_x;j++)
                    {
                            var x=i*TAM_TILE;
                            var y=j*TAM_TILE;

                            try
                            {
                                if(mapa[i][j]!=null && mapa[i][j]!="undefined")
                                {
                                    var terreno=new Image(25,25);
                                    terreno.src="/img/terrain/"+mapa[i][j]+".png";
                                    ctx.drawImage(terreno,x,y);
                                }
                            }catch(e)
                            {

                            }
                    } // del for(var j=0;j<(canvas.height/TAM_TILE);j++)

    } // del pintaterreno
}); 

context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
context.drawImage(mirror, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: this can help me i think... http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/2011-06-27-1/

Answer (score 0):

I have never done animation with canvases (only static graphs), but I think there is a couple of tips you should review (and don't worry, mi inglés tampoco es perfecto).

- First thing is to spot the exact function in code which is causing the 1seg lag: add a `console.log()` before and after the call to `ctx.clearRect()`. And also before and after `ctx.translate()`, `pinta_players()` and `pinta_terreno()`. The last one is my main suspect.
- If you are painting the whole visible area inside `pinta_terreno()` then `ctx.clearRect()` at the beginning of `mirror()` is not necesary.
- You may want to preload and store the images for the two players and the titles (it depends on how many titles, of course), so this step is not being done inside your paint function. This way you should have `ctx.drawImage(player1,x,y);` instead of `ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);` and `ctx.drawImage(terreno[i,j],x,y);` instead of `ctx.drawImage(terreno,x,y);`.
- also notice that if you are calling the `paint` function inside a loop/timer then you are clearing the canvas twice!
- This it the part I don't understand: are you passing a function to the `context.drawImage()` function? the first parameter of [`drawImage`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts) should be an image, video, canvas or another context.